# How to hide a parameter in the url Angular 2?

Tags: angular, url, parameters

I have a home page in which with a button click a go to another page. I want to see the new url in the next page but I want to hide the "usertoken" value from the url. Can someone help me?
I used skipLocationChange: true but it hide the whole url

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

    token:any;
    a:string;
  constructor (public parkingService: ParkingService, public root:Router) { 

  }
  ngOnInit(){

  }

        pass(passa)
          {

        this.a= passa.value;
        this.parkingService.setUserToken(this.a);
        //const mikos=this.a.length;
        this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(
          data=>
          {

        this.root.navigate(['/pages/iot-dashboard', { userToken: this.a} ]);

      },
      error => {
        window.alert("Παρακαλώ δώστε έγκυρο token για το χώρο στάθμευσης");
        console.error(error);
        this.root.navigate(['/pages/dashboard'] );

      },
      );
          }
```

***** I don't want a service solution because when I refresh the page tha token is lost

Comment: Instead use a singleton service to share data between the components. But the information can **always** seen by the end-user if they pry enough. It can never be securely hidden in the frontend application.

Answer (score 0):

remove it from url,  and use  service to pass data between components

Comment: I tried to have a service but when I am in the seconf page and refresh the token is lost, because it is taken from the first page to the service

Comment: you can use localstorage feature to do this localStorage.setItem(' ', ' '); 
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

the user token should be assigned by a service that is loaded into the component.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Angular Authentication](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

or

remove it from your URL, and use service to pass data between components

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pass the data during navigation without revealing it in the URL, then Angular can help you there. They have created an interface [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#navigationextras) just for this type of scenario only.

I have used your example and created a [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bcqv3e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fiot-dashboard.component.ts).

1. I am using navigationExtras inside HompPageComponent and passing the userToken with route.
2. I am reading this userToken inside IotDashboardComponent inside its constructor.

> Please note that NavigationExtras uses Local Storage to store the value and it will get purge as soon as the browser is refreshed. It is advisable to store the user tokens in session storage instead.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case of sensitive information such as token , it should not stored in local/session storage memory . Better to pass them as service. If possible cookie can also be used.

Now you problem is it lost after router navigate.

Design it as :-

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit { 
 constructor (public parkingService: ParkingService, public root:Router,private 
  tokenService:TokenService) { }

  pass(passa)
  {
  this.parkingService.getparkingDetails().subscribe(
      data=>
      {
        this.tokenService.setToken(this.a);
        this.root.navigate(['/pages/iot-dashboard', { userToken: this.a} ]);
  }
}
}
```

==In TokenService:

```
 token:string;
 constructor() { }

  setToken(){
     this.token="123";
  }
```

=== In iot-dashboard component:-

```
  constructor (private tokenService:TokenService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Token found"+this.tokenService.token);
  }
```

Even if you don't want to use service then store them in session storage with proper encoding.